# Create a Data Frame from Dictionary of Lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I have a python dictionary of lists and i want to create a multi indexing dataframe

```
data = {'row_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'row_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
```

From above code am getting output like below

```
       0  1  2  3
row_1  3  2  1  0
row_2  a  b  c  d
```

i want output like below

```
       values
row_1  3 
       2  
       1
       0
row_2  a  
       b  
       c  
       d
```

could you please help me out

Comment: What is the index of 2 1 0 and b c d then, in your desired output?

Comment: Row1 and row2 is the indexes

Comment: of 3 and of a, yes. You cannot have 2 1 0 and b c d without index, and you desired output suggests that they don't have an index.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly the expected output means?

Comment: The data seems to be in the right shape but probably you are looking for stack. pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index').stack()

Comment: @Vaishali When i tried to load into CSV i am not getting the same output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try `stack`

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index').stack()
Out[298]: 
row_1  0    3
       1    2
       2    1
       3    0
row_2  0    a
       1    b
       2    c
       3    d
dtype: object
```

Comment: When i try to convert it to CSV..i am missing the structure

Comment: @Shidev CSV is not structured data save method, try to save it into excel